# The value 'AddOrder' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I created a catalog api using asp.net core and cosmos db .I post a catalog data set. but i get following error.I debug it using break points the problem is my result body is null.

```html
{"errors":{"id":["The value 'AddOrder' is not valid."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"80000011-0005-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb"}
```

[Catalog controller code example](https://github.com/kajasumanie/calalogapi/blob/master/CalalogAPI/Controllers/BooksController.cs)

[Catalog repository code example](https://github.com/kajasumanie/calalogapi/blob/master/CalalogAPI/DocumentDBRepository.cs)

azure cosmos db structure :
[image]

What am i doing wrong ??

post json file :

```html
{
  "Id": 1,
  "venderId": 1,
  "IndustryName": "dsa",
  "ProductName": "sad",
  "CurrentQuantity": 1,
  "Tag": "sad",
  "Unit": "dsad",
  "Price": 34,
  "Class": "dsfs",
  "category": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "freg",
    "Description": "fdf",
    "subcategory": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "ergt",
        "Description": "erfwef"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace of the error?

Comment: How do you "post a catalog data set"? You need show us the payload as well as the definition of `Catalog` class

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_H-kgZiW9RI12e7u8cCRWlpZcsTgUCFT?usp=sharing

Comment: i upload it please help me. you can see my code structure  from above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I indicate the Id as Guid value. When try to  add the order, I gave the id value as 1,2,3....
But Guid value I need to pass the Id value like 80000011-0005-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb.
That is the problem .

Answer (score 2):

Your controller code is validating the Model and returning the BadRequest: https://github.com/kajasumanie/calalogapi/blob/master/CalalogAPI/Controllers/BooksController.cs#L41

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

The error you are seeing is unrelated to Cosmos DB, whatever payload you are sending is not valid for the `Catalog` class.

That class is not available in your repo, so it's hard to say. You should check the payload versus the model class and verify the format and requirements are met.

Comment: i tried with swagger also . there is no format problem

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_H-kgZiW9RI12e7u8cCRWlpZcsTgUCFT?usp=sharing